# How to throttle a node.js application?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to throttle hosted node.js applications. Those applications are user created in a web-ide and it seems, it can knock out the entire server.

Do we need to apply this in C++ and rebuild node.js by self ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using linux, you can try something like "renice" to set the priority of each of these processes.  Node.js is no different than hosting python, perl or PHP applications, any of them can take a lot of CPU if the program is written poorly or the application is processing many requests.

If by "knock out the entire server" you mean can cause a kernel panic, make sure you have the latest version of node.js and your server is up to date.  This should never happen.